# Refresh Access Token via Interceptor in apache httpclient

Tags: java, httpclient, interceptor

Using the interceptor, I try to update the access token. But the code doesn't work... How can I update the access token using the http client interceptor?

```
try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().
            addExecInterceptorAfter(ChainElement.PROTOCOL.name(), "a1", (request, scope, chain) -> {
                ClassicHttpResponse response = chain.proceed(request, scope);
                if (response.getCode() == HttpStatus.SC_UNAUTHORIZED) {
                    userAuthBean.updateAccessTokenFromAPI();
                    request.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + userAuthBean.getAccessToken());
                    chain.proceed(request, scope);
                }
                return response;
            })
            .build())
    {
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(uri);
        request.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + userAuthBean.getAccessToken());
        try (CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request)) {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            if (entity != null) {
                result = EntityUtils.toString(entity, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                System.out.println(result);
            }
        } catch (IOException | ParseException ioException) {
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code for retrying the request in case if 403 is obtained, ideally should not be in interceptor. Interceptors are to be generally written straightforward which manipulates the current* request/response and cause the call chain to process. They make your code hideous, and make debugging a lot more plain since the logic is hidden from plain-sight in most of the cases.

Generally, these interceptors can be best used to log the requests(To ELK/Kafka or wherever) and add missing attributes/headers if any for ***every** request going through the http client (Even this is a code-smell IMO).

Instead, what you need is chaining of `Function` as shown below,

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    getWithAuthTokenRetry.apply(new Request.Builder().url("http://google.com").build());
  }

  public static Function<Request, Response> get =
      (req) -> {
        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
        Response res = null;
        try {
          res = okHttpClient.newCall(req).execute(); // Simulate calls!!
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return res;
      };

  public static Function<Request, Response> getWithAuthTokenRetry =
      request -> {
        Function<Response, Response> authenticateAndRetryFunction =
            res -> {
              if (res != null && res.code() == 200) { //403 Here
                String authToken = "Generated AuthToken"; // Simulating new AuthToken
                Request updatedRequest = request.newBuilder().header("Auth", authToken).build();
                System.out.println(updatedRequest.headers());
                res = get.apply(updatedRequest);
              }
              return res;
            };
        return get.andThen(authenticateAndRetryFunction).apply(request);
      };
```

This is a very broad implementation, which does not deal with Exceptions properly, but I guess those can be figured out as per requirement.

Also, ClosableHttpClient need not be created for every request, create a instance of HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory with ClosableHttpClient.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. A clarifying question I would like to ask: do you think it makes sense to add a synchronization block to prevent the access token update method from being accessed simultaneously? It is unlikely that my service will be highly loaded, but in theory, it is probably possible to access it simultaneously. `code`

Comment: `if (res != null && res.code() == HttpStatus.SC_UNAUTHORIZED) { //403 Here
 synchronized (this) {
  if (req.header("Authorization").equals("Bearer " + userAuthBean.getAccessToken())) {
                                        userAuthBean.updateAccessTokenFromAPI();}}
        Request updatedRequest = req.newBuilder().header("Authorization", "Bearer " + userAuthBean.getAccessToken()).build();
        res = get.apply(updatedRequest);
}`

Comment: @stereouho This purely depends on your implementation. It makes sense to push this code to synchronized block only if you are running in a single machine. If multiple machines handle your request, still there is a chance it might be called in parallel. Else, its time to push the token to cache(Redis maybe). Time to read https://medium.com/@rohansaraf/distributed-locking-with-redis-ecb0773e7695